# Virtualenvs and version control in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, virtualenv

We're a team that are working on a python project. Everything is nicely checked into git, and most of us are using PyCharm. To my delight I discovered that [PyCharm do have venv support](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html).

However, I cannot store the venv settings in checked in to git. E.g. to use the venv everyone needs to have files checked out (`.idea/project-name.img` and `.idea/misc.xml`). Preferably I would like to be able to check in the (relative to repo-root) path to the venv, but as a workaround, is it possible to have the venv settings as purely local settings so that I do not have to have changed files in my `git status`?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html) solve your problem?

Comment: No, it's causing it. It's when I perform linked step files get changed, but committing them does not change setting for other people